# HashMap with threads inside

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

Here is my code:

[image: picture]

I want to organize a pool of threads. When I print the contents of the ThrdPool all the ids of the threads equal 1. I suppose it is because of the scope of the variable. Within the method addHotThrd() I create new HotThrd (reference type). Outside the block all the references will be cancelled.

How can I organize a hash map with an unknown number of threads?

```
  public ThrdPool(int hotThrds, long timeout) {
        this.freeThreadsMap = new HashMap(0);
        this.hotThreadsMap = new HashMap(0);
        this.hotThreads = hotThrds;
        this.timeout = timeout;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < hotThreads; i++) {            
            addHotThrd();
        }
    }

    public long addHotThrd() {
        HotThrd newThrd = new HotThrd();
        hotThreadsMap.put(newThrd, newThrd.getId());        
        return newThrd.getId();
    }
```

Comment: share the implementation of HotThrd.

Comment: Could you clarify what I should do. At this poitn I just want to start several independent threads, no synchronization is required so far .

Comment: Why can't you use thread.setName("XXX") ?

It will help with your logging as well ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your HotThrd class extends Thread class you can set the name of the thread during initialization.

```
class HotThrd extends Thread{
   HotThrd(String name){
      super(name);
   }
}

....
....
public long addHotThrd(int i) {
    HotThrd newThrd = new HotThrd("Thread"+i);
    hotThreadsMap.put(newThrd, newThrd.getId());        
    return newThrd.getId();
}
```